# Solving a System of Inequalities with an Orthogonality Constraint in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, sympy, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

I need to solve a system of inequalities for n variables where one of the inequalities has an orthogonality constraint. The inequalities are as follows.

In my particular problem, it has been proven that solving the system always results in one exact solution. Because of the orthogonality, I don't think I can use linear programming. Anyone have recommendations for efficient methods to solve in Python? Wolfram alpha is able to do it! (You can see an example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7B(2-x)x%2B+(1-y)y%3D0,+(2-x)+%3C%3D+(1-y),+x+%3E%3D+0,+x%2By+%3D+0+%7D,+%7Bx,+y%7D%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7B(3-x)x+%2B(2-y)y%2B+(1-z)z%3D0,+(3-x)+%3C%3D+(2-y),+(2-y)+%3C%3D+(1-z),+x+%3E%3D+0,+x%2B+y+%3E%3D+0,+x%2B+y%2B+z+%3D+0+%7D,+%7Bx,+y,+z%7D%5D)) I know sympy can't solve because it only can solve for univariate case. Please include runtime with whatever answer you give!

**Edit**: Just after posting this, I found z3. And it can somewhat do what I want. But I think it might be overkill and might not be as efficient as possible (hoping for linear in n:= the number of variables to solve for).

```py
from z3 import Solver, Real
def solve_inequalities(z):
    n = len(z)
    s = Solver()
    ys = [Real(f'y{i}') for i in range(n)]
    s.add(sum(ys) == 0)
    for i in range(1, n):
        s.add(sum(ys[:i]) >= 0)
    s.add(sum([(z[i]-ys[i])*ys[i] for i in range(n)]) == 0)
    for i in range(n-1):
        s.add(z[i]-ys[i] <= z[i+1]-ys[i+1])
    s.check()
    return s.model()
```

Comment: Each inequality can be written as two equality's. This would lead to a set of equations. I haven't tried it yet, but sure this wouldn't work? The two example do not look that difficult.

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon Can you be a little more explicit? I don't know what you mean. Can you please give an example or change one of my examples around to demonstrate what you mean? I know the inverse of what you are saying is true: Any equality can be written as two inequalitys but not sure what you are saying holds.

Comment: x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3  >= 12  ->  x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 - x_s = 12; xs> 0
I might shouldn't have said "two equalities", thats wrong. By introducing a slack variable you can get an equation and a very easy inequalities for the slack variable. She has to be bigger than 0.